# Could the duration of some gamma ray bursts be information from outside our universe?

Tags: big-bang-theory

Could we be in a system where a large mass explodes dispersing matter in all directions until gravity pulls it together with matter from other explosions until the maximum mass limit is reached, causing another  BIG BANG and the perpetual cycle starts again?
Could the gamma rays of unknown sources detected by the Compton gamma ray  observatory  be information  from  space outside our universe (outsidespace). Could a gamma ray of short duration describe a small universe and a long duration a large universe?

Comment: That not what the big bang is.  It isn't an explosion in space.  It is the expansion of space and the hot dense state of the early universe. So the answer is "no"

Comment: I dont think the situation you described is possible physically. What do you mean by gamma rays of unknown sources.